# Proxy pass / Forward request to specific server according to the Host header on Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, forward

so I have an Nginx server. And I'm trying to make it so if the host header is `test1.example.com`, it will proxy pass / forward the request to the specific IP. How could I do that? I've searched everywhere and can't find anything about it.

This is a repost by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want can be done using a map:

```
map $http_host     $my_host_map{
    "foo"         "192.168.1.1";
    "bar"         "192.168.1.2";
    "blort"       "192.168.1.3";
}
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name foo;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$my_host_map;
    }
}
```

with this I can curl my nginx server and set the host in the header:

```
curl -v --header Host:"blort" 192.168.1.100
```

Comment: how can i specify a port and protocol on the map? so one is ws://localhost:2134 and one http://localhost:2315

Comment: i keep getting "2022/07/30 23:17:58 [error] 1676#6160: *19 invalid URL prefix in "", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "completion_api" (completion_api is the host header i picked for the map)